# How can my program make IPv6 connections?

Tags: router, ipv6

I see in `Resource Monitor` that my torrent client `uTorrent` makes many connections to addresses in IPv6 range.

How can it be? My router is D-Link DIR-615 and has no any setting about IPv6. How can any program from inside network do any connection by IPv6?

**PROOF**

[image]

Comment: Well obviously you are either mistaken about it making IP6 connections outside your local network, or the router *does* support it.

Comment: My router is `DIR-615`. I don't have dozens of IPv6 addresses in local network (actually I have none, but even Microsoft has gifted me with several per each my computer, there would no be dozens).

Comment: Its because you installed `IPv6/Teredo`.  Here is what it does **"Teredo operates using a platform independent tunneling protocol designed to provide IPv6 (Internet Protocol version 6) connectivity by encapsulating IPv6 datagram packets within IPv4 User Datagram Protocol (UDP) packets. These datagrams can be routed on the IPv4 Internet and through NAT devices. Other Teredo nodes elsewhere called Teredo relays that have access to the IPv6 network then receive the packets, unencapsulate them, and route them on."**

Comment: **Bits 0 to 31 are set to the Teredo prefix (2001:0::/32).** So the comment made by `psusi` was indeed correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All addresses start with `2001:0:` which is the Teredo prefix. Teredo is a protocol designed to go through NAT to provide IPv6. There is a reason it is called after a shipworm (Teredo Navalis) :-)